# Why Context = None?

Tags: python, odoo-8

When I use the following code, it works fine:

```
def xyz(self, cr, uid, ids, vals, context=None):
    .......
    .......
    self.write(cr, uid, ids, vals, context=context)
```

But when I use the following code it throws an error:

> 'NoneType' object is not iterable.

```
def xyz(self, cr, uid, ids, vals, context=None):
    .......
    .......
    self.write(cr, uid, ids, vals, context=None)
```

Both method have same argument, but write method is different.

I am not updating context in both the code.

But second one throws an error, why?

Moreover why `context=None` in argument.

Comment: You are asking us why you wrote `context=None`?

Comment: Why are you making a recursive call to write? Are you sure you want to do that or you were trying to overwrite it?

Comment: Your question is not clear, and two functions below each other with exactly the same parameters and name seems to be a bad idea ..

Comment: Check some examples in the source code of other module to see how to program those methods. You must call the parent method

Comment: Please read question properly I asked you two things to answer 1) why we are using context=None in most of the methods? 2) Both code have same signature but error is due to context variable.

Comment: See the difference context=context and context=None in write method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two different things

```
def xyz(self, cr, uid, ids, vals, context=None):
```

It's method definition, in which you specify the **default value** of the parameteres, it means when you are not passing that parameter with method calling it will take **default value** for that parameters.

[Click here](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/) to see more

```
self.write(cr, uid, ids, vals, context=None)
```

This case defines that you are passing **None in context**. It's the concept of **keyword argument**.

[Click here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html) to see more

```
def xyz(self, cr, uid, ids, vals, context=None):
    .......
    .......
    self.write(cr, uid, ids, vals, context=context)
```

It shows that it will take default none in context **only if** you are not passing context value to that method **XYZ** and the same value will pass away to the write method so that it will not give you an error.

**context=context** means context have value that are assigned to context parameter at the time of calling, may or may not NONE. Try by passing none in **XYZ** calling will give you same error.

```
def xyz(self, cr, uid, ids, vals, context=None):
    .......
    .......
    self.write(cr, uid, ids, vals, context=None)
```

In second you are always passing none to the write method not the context=context so there is no chance other than none.

In generally, when you call any method never pass None to context simply set {} (blank dictionary), it won't give you errors at least.

And finally why you are getting this error is because of in write method somewhere CONTEXT (is actually passed NONE) is used for that model. If you want to know the reason then you need to find out all are places where write method is overridden for that model and where is the use of context.

Comment: Paragon answer. Perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown us where you are calling these functions, Most probably you are calling `xyz` with some iterable context. That's why in first case, context is not None and it works. Whereas in second case you are not preserving the context received in arguments and sending the hard-coded value `None` which ofcourse is not iterable. Anyway, what exactly do you want to accomplish? What you must be doing is something like -

```
xyz(..., context = []) # that's why context is iterable in first case and not second
```

In the first case, this `context` wouldn't be `None`.

Comment: See in the first case context=None in the argument so, in write method context should be None indirectly then still it's work fine.

Comment: @Ravi it is a default argument, in case you are passing it another value in function call, then default argument is not being used.

Comment: I have changed my answer, see if you get it now

Comment: you mean to say is that in argument if we specify context = None it will consider context = [] , so if i change second write with self.write(cr, uid, ids, vals, context= []) it will work right?

Comment: No that's not what I mean, Show us how you are calling `xyz`, which is causing the exception

Comment: You are bit right but actually answer is I have to change second write method like this self.write(cr, uid, ids, vals, context= {}) because it is dictionary.